# Clean up Rails Routes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

Is there any way I can DRY up this Rails 4 routes.rb code?

```
  match '/oauth/apps/' => 'oauth/applications#index', :as => :oauth_applications, :via => :get
  match '/oauth/apps/new/' => 'oauth/applications#new', :as => :new_oauth_application, :via => :get
  match '/oauth/apps/new/' => 'oauth/applications#create', :via => :post
  match '/oauth/apps/:id/' => 'oauth/applications#show', :as => :oauth_application, :via => :get
  match '/oauth/apps/:id/edit/' => 'oauth/applications#edit', :as => :edit_oauth_application, :via => :get
  match '/oauth/apps/:id/edit/' => 'oauth/applications#update', :via => :post
  match '/oauth/apps/:id/destroy/' => 'oauth/applications#destroy', :as => :destroy_oauth_application, :via => :delete
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use `namespace` and `resources`:

```
namespace :oauth do
  resources :apps, controller: "applications", as: :applications
end
```

This is not 100% identical (the names of some of your routes have changed) but it is the way you *should* be building your routes, and you should change the rest of your app to reflect the change.

The primary difference is your names for the `create` and `destroy` routes have gone away; these routes *shouldn't have names anyways*. When you want to create/destroy a model, you should be using `oath_applications_path`, with  `method: :post` or `method: :delete`, not `oath_apps_new_path`/`destroy_oauth_application_path`.

My way also uses the correct verb (PUT) for updates.

Your `rake routes:`

```
       oauth_applications GET    /oauth/apps(.:format)             oauth/applications#index
    new_oauth_application GET    /oauth/apps/new(.:format)         oauth/applications#new
           oauth_apps_new POST   /oauth/apps/new(.:format)         oauth/applications#create
        oauth_application GET    /oauth/apps/:id(.:format)         oauth/applications#show
   edit_oauth_application GET    /oauth/apps/:id/edit(.:format)    oauth/applications#edit
                          POST   /oauth/apps/:id/edit(.:format)    oauth/applications#update
destroy_oauth_application DELETE /oauth/apps/:id/destroy(.:format) oauth/applications#destroy
```

My `rake routes` (reordered to match yours):

```
    oauth_applications GET    /oauth/apps(.:format)          oauth/applications#index
 new_oauth_application GET    /oauth/apps/new(.:format)      oauth/applications#new
                       POST   /oauth/apps(.:format)          oauth/applications#create
     oauth_application GET    /oauth/apps/:id(.:format)      oauth/applications#show
edit_oauth_application GET    /oauth/apps/:id/edit(.:format) oauth/applications#edit
                       PUT    /oauth/apps/:id(.:format)      oauth/applications#update
                       DELETE /oauth/apps/:id(.:format)      oauth/applications#destroy
```

Comment: Wow thank you for this. I never thought of doing it this way and I guess doing things the conventional way is better then anything else.